# Connecting to remote linux server with VSCode through WSL - File location issue?

Tags: visual-studio-code, digital-ocean, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When attempting to use VS Code / WSL to remote into a linux server hosted as a Digital Ocean droplet, we're getting this error:

```
[17:38:24.258] Log Level: 2
[17:38:24.260] remote-ssh@0.63.0
[17:38:24.260] win32 x64
[17:38:24.262] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+100.100.10.100", attempt 1
[17:38:24.263] "remote.SSH.useLocalServer": false
[17:38:24.263] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[17:38:24.263] "remote.SSH.remotePlatform": {"$remote_server_name":"linux"}
[17:38:24.264] "remote.SSH.sshPath": undefined
[17:38:24.264] "remote.SSH.sshConfigurationFile": undefined
[17:38:24.264] "remote.SSH.useFlock": true
[17:38:24.265] "remote.SSH.lockfilesInTmp": false
[17:38:24.265] "remote.SSH.localServerDownload": auto
[17:38:24.265] "remote.SSH.remoteServerListenOnSocket": false
[17:38:24.265] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[17:38:24.266] SSH Resolver called for host: 100.100.10.100
[17:38:24.266] Setting up SSH remote "100.100.10.100"
[17:38:24.278] Using commit id "ea3859d4ba2f3e577a159bc91e3074c5d8c0523" and quality "stable" for server
[17:38:24.285] Install and start server if needed
[17:38:25.556] Checking ssh with "ssh -V"
[17:38:25.713] > OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5

[17:38:25.726] Running script with connection command: ssh -T -D 53538 "100.100.10.100" bash
[17:38:25.735] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[17:38:26.931] > no such identity: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
> ]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[17:38:26.933] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[17:38:26.940] > root@100.100.10.100: Permission denied (publickey).
> The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
```

As far as I can see, the issue lies with

```
[17:38:26.931] > no such identity: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
```

However

```
ssh -vv root@100.100.10.100 -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Successfully connects in the debug and server is accessed

```
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
```

So this must be some issue with specifying the location of `id_rsa` in the config file for VS Code.

```
Host 100.100.10.100
  HostName 100.100.10.100
  User root
  ForwardAgent yes
  IdentityFile /home/autosermo/.ssh/id_rsa
```

We have tried everything we can think of for the value of `IdentityFile` (...`~/.ssh/id_rsa` etc) but cannot nail it down.

What are the other possible locations / what path should be provided to `IdentityFile` here?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

WSL is a bit of a red-herring here.  When you are using the "*Remote - SSH*" extension in VSCode, you aren't going through WSL at all.  As you can see from this line in the output ...

`[17:38:25.713] > OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5`

... It's using OpenSSH for Windows.

The location for your private key in OpenSSH should be `%userprofile%/.ssh` (so something like `C:\Users\username\.ssh`).  Try placing it there.  Also try executing your `ssh` command from PowerShell or cmd rather than WSL, since that's the one being used by VSCode.

Comment: I think the issue is arising because the SSH keys are being created / stored through WSL - So WSL is putting them somewhere, but the result of `ls ~/.ssh/*.pub` (`/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`) in not the directory we need. So in other words - Where is WSL actually putting these keys on Windows?

Comment: WSL actually stores ssh-related files in `\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\home\YOUR-WSL-USERNAME\.ssh`

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue since I used the same environment (Windows with WSL and VS Code SSH - Remote extension) as the original asker and I finally resolved it. Just like NotTheDr01ds said, the main issue is that it's using **OpenSSH for Windows**, so it will **only recognize IdentityFile located in Windows directory**. So what you need to do are two things (step 2 may be skipped if you can successfully remote connect with VS code after step 1):

1. Place the .pem file or security file in some Windows directory.
2. Go to that Windows directory using Powershell and use these commands to basically do a "chmod 400" equivalent command:

   icacls.exe id_rsa /reset
   icacls.exe id_rsa /grant:r "$($env:username):(r)"
   icacls.exe id_rsa /inheritance:r

This works for me. Hope it helps!